# Equivalent to MapThread for lists of unequal length

Tags: map

I am looking for the equivalent to the built-in function `MapThread` that allows to map a function over lists of different length.

`MapThread` works fine for lists of equal length, i.e.

```
In:= MapThread[f[#1, #2] &, {Range[2], Range[2]}]

Out:= {f[1, 1], f[2, 2]}
```

Now the arguments shall be lists of unequal length and I want to map `f` over all entries of the first list for each entry of the second list .

How can you do this in Mathematica?

[Edit]

I try to apply it to

```
{listData2[wi][[#, 1]] - 
    listData2[wi][[listStPtsRestr[[#2, 1, 1]], 1]], 
   listData2[wi][[#, 2]]} & /@ 
 Range[listStPtsRestr[[1, 1, 1]], listStPtsRestr[[1, 1, 1]] + ndt, dn]
```

where #2 shall be mapped over e.g. Range[10]

```
Outer[{listData2[wi][[#, 1]] - 
      listData2[wi][[listStPtsRestr[[#2, 1, 1]], 1]], 
     listData2[wi][[#, 2]]} & /@ 
   Range[listStPtsRestr[[#2, 1, 1]], listStPtsRestr[[#2, 1, 1]] + ndt, 
    dn] &, Range[10]]
```

did not work.

[Edit2]

```
Table[{listData2[wi][[#, 1]] - 
       listData2[wi][[listStPtsRestr[[n, m, 1]], 1]], 
      listData2[wi][[#, 2]]} & /@ 
    Range[listStPtsRestr[[n, m, 1]], listStPtsRestr[[n, 1, 1]] + ndt, 
     dn], {n, 1, 18}, {m, 1, listStPtsRestr[[n]] // Length}];
```

Table does exactly what I want, though is a little bit slow for large amounts of data.

Comment: Perhaps `Outer[]`?

Comment: I need to write it as a pure function. Does this work with `Outer[]`?

Comment: @DisplayName have you tried?

Comment: Please see my edit in the opening post. Ah ok I think I should do the whole think with `Outer[]` since it probably requires two slots. The problem is that the range of slot 1 depends on the value of slot 2.

Comment: Maybe I should simply stick to `Table` in this case not too complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: But then I need a double table which slows my code pretty much down.

Comment: Please prepare a minimal example of data and expected output.

Comment: This is not so easy, since I deal with two different tables and need to cross-index them. I think `Outer` is a good idea, but the Range of the first slot depends on the number of the second slot and I think this is not possible to do with `Outer`. All the arguments must come before `&`. What I need is something like a nested `Map`. I don't know whether this is feasible or one should stick to `Table`. I added the Table solution to my initial code. I know this isn't pretty much a help for you to help. :(

Comment: Surely you can supply a minimal _working_ example, together with expected output?

Answer (score 6):

```
result = Tuples[f[Range@4, Range@3]]
```

> {f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 1], 
>    f[3, 2], f[3, 3], f[4, 1], f[4, 2], f[4, 3]}

Comment: (+1) But `Tuples[f[Range@2, Range@2]]` gives {f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[2, 1], f[2, 2]} which is not what the OP is after (or is it)?

Comment: @tomd - It seems the only logical way to handle "... lists of unequal length..." in the ambiguous description, but beats me, since OP has not provided an example of desired output.

Comment: While MapThread cannot auto comprehend arguments, Thread can, for example : ```Thread@Style[{SOXL, SOXL_QT0 .025, SOXL_QT0 .5, 
   SOXL_QT0 .975}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1.], RGBColor[
   0.6470588235294118, 0.16470588235294117`, 0.16470588235294117`], 
   RGBColor[0, 0, 0.5450980392156862], RGBColor[
   0.13333333333333333`, 0.5450980392156862, 0.13333333333333333`]}, 
  FontSize -> 8]``` Or example ``Thread@ff[{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}, 5]`` if the Style function itself can thread.